# Trigger that prevent adding new rows if ID number is too high

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table "Months" with 12 rows(obviously) and I want to add a trigger that prevent adding new row if ID number is over 12

```
CREATE TRIGGER "no_more_months" BEFORE INSERT ON "months"
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF NEW.ID_Month>12 THEN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '12345'
SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'check constraint on Months failed';
END IF;
END;
```

But somehow it doesn't work and still adds new rows

Comment: Does ID_Month is an artificial primary key or the month's name? You could use a constraint on the primary key to be less than 12 and a auto incrementation from 1 to 12 on insert.

Comment: You could just have an update instead

Comment: @Fleury26 ID_Month is primary key with numbers from 1 to 12. So I keep this trigger and just add constraint with check ID<13?

Comment: @ZwykłyUżytkownik if you absolutely need to have a signal yes, if not just the constraint will do the job. The constraint is the one that will control the ID_Month, the trigger will be just there for the message. I'll post an answer to guide you

Comment: @Fleury26 Got the reason.  I have auto_increment and when I add rows like that (NULL,"value") it passes but when I change NULL to number (13,"value") it stops. So how to make it work with auto_increment?

Comment: @ZwykłyUżytkownik You probably have auto incrementation on and you accept Null values. If your not suppose to accept null just add "NOT NULL". And be sure to make this column a primary key to be sure it's unique. I can provide an exemple if you want

Comment: @Fleury26 Ok, it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comment section, just a constraint should do the job.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Months] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Months_ID_Months CHECK ([ID_Months] <= 12 AND [ID_Months] > 0);
```

If you absolutely need a custom error message look at this article : [MySql Signals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html)